# UWP get form in webviewer returning 'about:blank' rather than form values

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp

We have a mobile app which shows an html page with some javascript in a webviewer.

In this page we have a form.  IT looks something like:

```
<form method="get" action = "" id="mainform">
<input name="EXAMPLE_NAME" id"EXAMPLE_NAME" placeholder="" type="text" maxlength="35"/>    
</form>
```

So far so good.  The user is able to view this input and fill it in with data.  They then press a button on the xaml page which calls a function that does:

```
Browser.Eval("submitMainForm()")
```

In the javascript on the page we have that function, which looks like:

```
function submitMainForm() {    
var x = document.getElementById("mainForm").submit();
}
```

Back in the C# code we have handlers for the resulting navigation.  They look like:

```
async void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
```

and

```
void OnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
```

This works well in iOS and Android.  We get the WebNavigatingEventArgs in the handler, and the value from the field that we are showing in the webviewer (inside of mainform) are stored in there.

So, for example, e.Url in the OnNavigating and OnNavigated handlers would look something like:

"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.exampleapp/files/Example.html?EXAMPLE_NAME=Test"

We parse this string to get the values we care about (Test, in this case), and all is well.

On UWP, however, things work a lot less well.  On Navigating is never called at all, and the call to OnNavigated just has "about:blank" stored in its WebNavigateEventArgs url value.

Does anyone know what might be going on here, and/or have a way that I can fix it?  I need a way to get the results from my call to the get form as I do in the other 2 platforms, rather than "about:blank".  Ideally, I'd also like to get the OnNavigated call, but the important thing is the data.

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: You have not set the  `action` property in you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For html form submitting, you need add the `action` url that used to received parameter. For example:

```
<form id="Myform" action="HomePage.html">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you invoke submit, the *firstname* *lastname* field will be sended to `HomePage.html` page.  I create `HomePage` that **Build Action** is `Content` in native uwp project.

[image]

Please note you could not create html in forms project. Otherwise the webview could get navigate to the right url.

This is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WebView/blob/master/WebViewSample/WebViewSample/index.html#L17) please check.

Comment: Thank you for this sample.  I was able to get it running and working, and it definitely shed light on my problem.

In my code, when I changed action="" to action="www.google.com" or similar, I was able to get the values that I cared about in the URL of the WebNavigatedEventArgs.

Unfortunately, it also pointed my browser to google, so I'm not quite set yet, but I am getting closer.

I want the Url to be populated (not with "about?blank"), but I don't actually want to go anywhere.  In iOS/Android the blank action accomplishes that.  Do you know a way to do it in UWP?

Comment: If you do not go anywhere, you could set the action url as the `index.html` in above scenario. In other words, using current html page url.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do that and having difficulties.  Ultimately I discovered that the reason that your original solution didn't work for me was that my form had so many values in it that the URL was too long.  Once I shrunk the form down the error went away.  I really appreciate your assistance.